# How implement a basic Unit Test with Firebase and Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, unit-testing, junit

I'm trying to create a unit test with JUnit 4 and Mockito and Firebase. However, I'm confused on the mocking part. The idea was just to perform a basic test in the login method, but when it arrives in the ' signInWithEmailAndPassword() ' method, JUnit skips the Listener and ends the test. I'm not sure how to do a unit test using Firebase. Could someone show me a very basic example with this code I'm making, please? It was just @Test's implementation of login verification with valid email and password. Basically I would just like to know how to do a login verification unit test using firebase,junit and mockito. I would be very grateful to anyone who could help.

This is the code :

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LoginActivityTest extends TestCase {

```
Task<AuthResult> successTask;
Task<AuthResult> failureTask;

@Mock
FirebaseAuth mAuth;


@Before
public void onBefore(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

}

@Test
public void testVerifyUserLoggedWithValidEmailAndPassword(){
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    String email = "goku@gmail.com";
    String password = "testtest";
    Mockito.when(mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)).thenReturn(successTask);


}
```

}

Comment: You don't mock the class you are testing (`FirebaseAuth`). You mock dependencies of the class you are testing. So for instance, if `FireBaseAuth` used a component which talked to a database, you'd mock that component, as you don't have a database during your unit tests. Notice that you are not using `auth` at all in your test.

Comment: @tgdavies There's no reason to unmock `FirebaseAuth` and that class shouldn't be tested anyway. I'm confident Firebase have tested their own code sufficiently enough.

Comment: So I can't mock third-party classes, only the ones I created, right? Sorry, I'm still new to Unit Testing

Comment: You can and should mock third party classes if they are used by the class you are testing. I interpreted your post as a test of `FirebaseAuth`, what class are you testing?

Comment: So, I'm trying to create a unit test for login with valid email and password, but I don't know if this is correct. For example, if I want to test the 'signInWithEmailAndPassword()' method, how would I do that? In the code I didn't write any of this because I really don't know how to do a unit test with Firebase

Comment: For example, I want to test this method here: auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("","").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult> ...  how would i do ?